# Function to store into into a variable

Tags: php

I am trying to update the class we are using to connect to the database and there are TON's of calls to something along the lines of `$res->fetchInto($_row);` which I don't want to replace everything to `$_row = $res->fetchInto();`. Is there a way to call a function and have it return the results to the variable name passed to the function?

Example:

```
$_row = array();

$res->fetchInto($_row);

echo "Lets print out the array<br>";
echo "<pre>";
print_r($_row);
echo "</pre>";
```

```
echo "Lets loop through all outputted rows
while ($res->fetchInto($_row)) {
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($_row);
    echo "</pre>";
    echo "<hr>";
}
```

```
function fetchInto($arrName)    {
    // PROCESSING HERE
    return $arrName;
}
```

Comment: Pass it as reference, see: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You should pass it by reference**.

In the function

```
function fetchInto(&$arr, $res) {
    $arr = $res->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); // Assuming 1$res->fetch()1 returns an associative array of the next row
}
```

In caller

```
$_row = array();
$res = $pdoStatement; // Assuming a PDOStatement object
fetchInto($_row, $res);

echo "Let's print out the array<br>";
echo "<pre>";
print_r($_row);
echo "</pre>";
```

> In this code, `$arr` is passed by reference, so any changes made to `$arr` inside the fetchInto function will affect `$_row` outside the function.

Comment: Thank you this worked perfect except the original function would loop through the rows when multiple were returned. As I cant add the code here I edited my question